# Unable to hide android start up white window with android:windowDisablePreview

Tags: android

Every time on my android app start up there is a white window for few seconds. I have a splash screen in my app which I want to display instead of this white screen. I have set windowDisablePreview to true but its not working. How to fix this issue.
true

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ankitsrivastava.recyclerview">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <!--Splash Screen-->
    <activity
        android:name=".app.SplashScreen"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--Main Activity-->
    <activity android:name=".app.MainActivity">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Styles.xml

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Check if you are loading a big image as Background for splash or you are doing some heavy duty task in onCreate/onResume of Splash. Put it in PostDelayed or load it later.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should follow the instructions at [bignerdranch](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) on how to create a splash screen the right way. It is a little long to copy here, but basically you set your splash activity theme android:windowBackground value to a static XML drawable. 
You can even take it a step further and have the splash activity animate with the drawable after it loads. A simple suggestion, is to have a circular progress bar in the splash layout, which will animate around the icon in the center of the Background Drawable, after activity is loaded (and app is presumably still loading data).